# How are swapping if statements in an if condition called?

Tags: php, if-statement

After four hours of searching on the internet how swapping if statements of if conditions are called and was not successful, I decided to open a question. There was a special name for that. Can somebody help me further?

```
// These conditions:

if ($a === 1){
    // Do something...
}

// Get to these conditions.
if (1 === $a){
    // Do something...
}
```

How is this type of writing called?

Comment: a preference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `inverted` conditions are called `Yoda conditions`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions